# Why won't my UI reflect a change in the @State property?

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to make a graph app, but animating it using a @State property does not help, for some reason.

```
struct GraphBars: View {

    @State var percent: CGFloat

    var body: some View {

        Capsule()
            .fill(Color.black)
            .frame(width: 50, height: self.percent)
    }
}

struct TEST3: View {

    @State var bar1: CGFloat = 90.0

       var body: some View {


        GeometryReader { gg in

        VStack {

            Button(action: {
                self.bar1 = 300.0
            }) {
                Text("Hello")
            }



            GraphBars(percent: bar1)

            }
```

However, pressing the button does not increase the height of the bar as I thought it would. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use @Binding to transfer a variable back and forth between two Views otherwise the parent View doesn't get a notice of the variable change.

Do it like this:

```
struct GraphBars: View {

    @Binding var percent: CGFloat

    var body: some View {

        Capsule()
            .fill(Color.black)
            .frame(width: 50, height: self.percent)
    }
}

struct Test3: View {

    @State var bar1: CGFloat = 90.0

    var body: some View {

        GeometryReader { gg in

            VStack {

                Button(action: {
                    self.bar1 = 300.0
                }) {
                    Text("Hello")
                }
                GraphBars(percent: self.$bar1)

            }
        }
    }
}
```